# how can i fix the error about JFXSnackbar in my java code?

Tags: java, javafx

I write code using javaFx to display a snackbar on my loginForm project, but the compiler show an error when I define a snackbar like this:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       errorMsg = new JFXSnackbar(rightBox);
    }    


@FXML
public void btnExit(){
    Platform.exit();
}

@FXML
public void btnLogin(){
    if (unameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        errorMsg.show("Username field is empty! ",1500);
        return;
    }
    if (passField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        errorMsg.show("Password field is empty! ",1500);
        return;
    }
```

** The compiler show that error:
  errorMsg.show("Password field is empty! ",1500);
  required: SnackbarEvent
  found: String,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; the method accepts a single argument of type `SnackbarEvent`, not two arguments of type `String` and `int`. Fix the code by supplying the correct argument. As far as I know there's no online Javadoc for JFoenix, so here's [the source code](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/fb03a39e3feeb1a645aa98dbf2e8c0cb918b7fec/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXSnackbar.java#L372) of `SnackbarEvent` so you can see what constructors are available.

Comment: On top of that, the `show` method seems to be private. It appears you [should be calling `enqueue`](http://www.jfoenix.com/documentation.html?search=JFXSnackbar#SnackBar).